# Excel countifs with multiple criteria using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the follwing COUNTIFS function in Excel file over BA column:

```
=(COUNTIFS(E$2:E2;E2;$G$2:G2;G2;$I$2:I2;I2;$N$2:N2;N2;$O$2:O2;O2;$R$2:R2;R2)=1)*1
```

I have over 150K records so Excel crashes. Is it possible to improve the formula or use vba code to do the same?

Here's a sample:
[image]

Comment: Could you post a mock up of your data as is and the expected result

Comment: It is still not apparent what you are trying to achieve with the formula, a little more explanation would help.

Comment: i'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but if I was to hazard a guess, you are trying to count the number of 1s (true) in column BA? If so, I suggest you try `=SUM(BA:BA)`

Answer (score 1):

In the case of the example, I'm trying to count unique records depending on multiple criteria. The formula `=(COUNTIFS(E$2:E2;E2;$G$2:G2;G2;$I$2:I2;I2;$N$2:N2;N2;$O$2:O2;O2;$R$2:R2;R2)=1)*1` works like a charm, however I wanted to do the same using vba.

```
Sub CountIfsFormula()
Dim varFilas As Long
Dim vari As Long

    On Error GoTo errCountIfsFormula
    varFilas = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For vari = 2 To varFilas
        Range("BA" & vari).Formula = "=(COUNTIFS(E$2:E" & vari & ",E" & vari & ",$G$2:G" & vari & ",G" & vari & ",$I$2:I" & vari & ",I" & vari & ",$N$2:N" & vari & ",N" & vari & ",$O$2:O" & vari & ",O" & vari & ",$R$2:R" & vari & ",R" & vari & ")=1)*1"
        Range("BA" & vari).Value = CStr(Range("BA" & vari).Value)
    Next vari

    Exit Sub
```

With about 200K record it takes aprox 1 hour. Maybe there is a faster way to do it.